# Laravel hasMany relationship not resturning values without parentheses

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this model, say `City`. And it has a OneToMany relationship with another model, say, `Citizen`.

On the city model, I have defined a relationship helper function

```php
public function citizens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Citizen::class, 'city_id', 'id');
}
```

Now my problem is that, in a command, I have :

```php
$cities = City::with('citizens')->get();
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $citizens = $city->citizens->pluck('user');
}
```

Yet it doesn't return anything. To get values I must turn this line to

```php
$cities = City::all();
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $citizens = $city->citizens()->get()->pluck('user');
}
```

Does anyone have a clue how this might happen ? This started happening today with no apparent reason.

**EDIT**

To further illustrate the situation,

```php
$cities = City::with('citizens')->get();
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    dd($city->citizens()->count()); // => 5
    dd($city->citizens->count()); // => 0
}
```

Here are the models definitions

```php
// City.php

class City extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    protected $table = 'cities';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $perPage = 20;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'unique_code',
        'extra_attributes'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string',
        'codes' => 'array',
        'extra_attributes' => SchemalessAttributes::class,
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->id = $model->id ?: Str::orderedUuid();
        });
    }

    public function toSearchableArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
 
    public function citizens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Citizen::class, 'city_id', 'id');
    }
}


// Citizen.php

class Citizen extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $perPage = 20;
    protected $table = "citizens";

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'level_id',
        'city_id',
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->id = $model->id ?: Str::orderedUuid();
        });
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id')->withTrashed();
    }
 
    public function city() {
        return $this->hasOne(City::class, 'id', 'city_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `$city->citizens->get()->pluck(...)`?

Comment: @sta Shouldn't have to do that; Collections (which `$city->citizens` is) have a `pluck()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck. @TDk, can you show the definition of your `$city` variable? You might be eager-loading `citizens` as an empty Collection, and since `citizens()` would be a new query, this would override that.

Comment: @sta nope I really mean `->citizens()->get()`. @Tim I load the city object like so : `$cities = City::all();` Then iterate with a foreach loop.

Comment: Ah, so each `$city` in the loop is simply an iteration of `City::all()`. In that case, there shouldn't be any reason that `$city->citizens->pluck(...)`, `$city->citizens()->pluck(...)` and/or `$city->citizens()->get()->pluck(...)` would return different results... You might have to debug this with something like `if ($city->citizens->pluck(...) != $city->citizens()->get()->pluck(...){ dd($city->citizens, $city->citizens()->get()); }`; that could help you visualize the difference. The note below about eagerloading using `with()` is a good one too; difference between 2 and count($cities) queries

Comment: `$city->citizens` and `$city->citizens()->get()` should be equivalent, as Tim Lewis says. You must be doing something to change this default behaviour.

Comment: So I used dd on both expressions and got an empty Collection object for the `->citizens->pluck(...)` one and one with the expected amount of models for the other

Comment: @miken32 I don't think I've modified anything towards modifying this behavior however... @Tim Lewis even when eager loading with `City::with('citizens')` the `->mandates` magic method returns an empty collection

Comment: can you share City model code entirely?

Comment: @OMR done so ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

the relation between `City` and `Citizen` is City hasMany Citizens...

In Laravel, hasMany relation reverse is belongsTo **Not** hasOne, see [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

so you should correct the relation In Citizen Model like this:

```
public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'city_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues, one of which OMR has highlighted (you've used an incorrect relationship in your Citizen class), but that isn't the main issue. You're trying to pluck another relationship but unless you explicitly tell it to, Laravel won't eager load that relationship. You've only told it to eager load the Citizen relationship, not the User relationship. Thankfully, Laravel does support [nested relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading). You need to update your query thusly:

```php
$cities = City::with('citizens.user')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this issue is by eager loading the citizens when you're getting your cities, that way you wont be executing too many queries (as you will have to get citizens for each city individually), it will save you a lot of execution time in the future when the database gets bigger if you do this :

```
$cities = City::with('citizens')->get();
foreach($cities as $city) {
    $items = $city->citizens->pluck('...');
}
```

Comment: This certainly makes for more efficient code, but it doesn't solve the problem. At best it works around it.

Comment: So I did what you suggested, and still there's a difference in output. See the EDIT part in my original post